# what is wrong with this simple c++ recursive function to reverse the string?

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
```

//swap function to swap the characters in a string

```
void swap(char &x,char &y){
    char temp;
    temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
}
```

//recursive function to reverse the string

```
string reverse(string s,int be,int en){
    //base case
    if(be>=en){
        return s ;
    }
    //working
    swap(s[be],s[en]);
    reverse(s,be+1,en-1);
}
int main(){
    string s,s1,s2;
    cin>>s;
    s1=s;
    int l=s.length();

    s2=reverse(s,0,l-1);
```

//checking if the reverse string is same as original string

```
    if (s1==s2)
    {
        cout<<"true"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"false"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Additionally, if your compiler didn't properly warn you about your `reverse`() failing to return a value, find a better C++ compiler. Your code is undefined behavior, and every self-respecting C++ compiler should be, at least, issuing a very loud, obnoxious complaint.

Comment: You need to `return reverse(s,be+1,en-1);`, not just call it - that way you pass the result back through the stack.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problam:

```
  string reverse(string s,int be,int en){
      if(be>=en){
          return s ;
      }
      swap(s[be],s[en]);
      reverse(s,be+1,en-1);
>     RETURN WHAT?
  }

  s2 = reverse(s,0,l-1); // Return value is gone???
```

Your `string reverse(string, int, int);` has no returned values. When its return value is assigned to `s2`, we can't tell what actually happens. It's an UB.

To fix it, simply return the reversed string:

```
      swap(s[be],s[en]);
>     return reverse(s,be+1,en-1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return reverse(s, be+1, en-1), not just calling it

And there's no need to have an extra string s

The code below works for me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(char& x,char& y){
    char temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

string reverse(string s,int be,int en){
    //base case
    if(be >= en){
        return s;
    }
    //working
    swap(s[be],s[en]);

   **return reverse(s, be+1, en-1);**
}

int main(){

    string s1,s2;

    cout << "what is your string?" << endl;
    cin >> s1;

    int l = s1.length();

    s2 = reverse(s1,0,l-1);

    if (s1==s2){
        cout << "true" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "false" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are passing the string by value, so it is copied, then the characters of the copy are swapped, but the original string remains unchanged. Pass the string by reference and make `void` as the return type or make the function actually return string.

Version with passing by reference:

```
void reverse(string& s,int be,int en){
    //base case
    if(be>=en){
        return;
    }
    swap(s[be],s[en]);
    reverse(s,be+1,en-1);
}
```

Version with string as return type and passing by value:

```
string reverse(string s,int be,int en){
        //base case
        if(be>=en){
            return s;
        }
        swap(s[be],s[en]);
        return reverse(temp,be+1,en-1);
    }
```

The latter version sticks to the principle of **preferring return over output parameters**, but the former prevents unnecessary, multiple copies, so in this case I would stick with the former if you don't want to re-write the function so that it isn't recursive, because for a string of size n, you have to make n/2 copies, which is a lot (think about a string that's e.g. thousand characters long - copying it 500 times just to reverse it just doesn't sound right).

Comment: In what way does it "ruin" it? It's enough to copy the string before passing it to the function.

Comment: Sorry I looked at the wrong code. But still, it isn't a good practice.

Comment: No problem. If that's the reason for your downvote, I'd be grateful to take it back also ;p

Comment: What is it about that practice that is bad? Do you think it's better to copy a string possibly hundreds or thousands of times just to reverse it instead?

The vote is not locked - you can retract it anytime you want unless you don't want to do so, in which case you can just say it and that would more ok.

Comment: You can't retract your vote unless 1) within 1 minute after casting, or 2) post is edited.